# Edit code where indentation is only one space?

Tags: discussion, edits, code-formatting

I've read a couple of posts here and I came to the conclusion that you should not change the indentation style of a post. It's up to the poster to decide that. And that also includes how many spaces an indentation should be.

But how about code with only one space for the indentation? I would almost go as far as saying that it is objectively too small.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that's fine. Any edit that you're making needs to do two things:

- improve the presentation and/or readability of the post, and
- respect the author's intent.

You can assume it is never the author's intent to post code that is difficult or impossible to read. As such, breaking up long lines to reduce scrolling, increasing indents to sane levels, and adding whitespace are all fine edits, as long as you do them judiciously.

Please make your edit count—meaning, fix all the problems with the post, not just add indentation.

Comment: It might be easier to get everybody to agree when you add "only edit indentation after the question was answered".

Comment: @Hans Maybe, but I don't agree with that. Making the code readable is just as important *before* the question is answered, if not *more* important. I'll admit I wrote this answer assuming a language where whitespace is insignificant. If you're programming in one of those god-forsaken languages where it does matter, you do need to be much more careful to ensure that you're not accidentally covering up a bug (or introducing a new one). That would make answering confusing.